# Update a python list given a list of indexes

Tags: python, list, optimization

How do you update a list, given a list of indexes to be udpated.

For example, lets say we have a list

```
l = ['4', '5', '8', '19', '2', '53', '125']
```

and

```
indexes = [0, 1, 4, 5]
```

Say we want to update these indexes to an `int`. The desired updated list will be

```
l = [4, 5, '8', '19', 2, 53, '125']
```

Yes we can do easily with a loop like:

```
for i in indexes:
    l[i] = int(l[i])
```

But actually, something like this is a bit faster

```
l[0] = int(l[0])
l[1] = int(l[1])
l[4] = int(l[4])
l[5] = int(l[5])
```

The difference in speed may not be noticeable here since there are only 4 items, but once there are 40 or more, you can see the difference.  But its also a pain to write so many repetitive statements.

Is there a way to optimize this a bit more, maybe using `map` and generating a list to update the list (based on specific indexes only or something like that)

Comment: If the list of indexes is dynamic, the loop is the only way to do it.

Comment: Have you actually measured the difference in speed with a larger list? I think it will be negligible. The cost of converting a string to an int is far more than the cost of looping over a list.

Comment: Note that PEP 8 [specifically lists](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) lowercase "L" as a name to avoid in Python.

Comment: I was seeing a ~10% increase with the loop (compared to the no loop version), using `timeit` and updating about 40 items in the list

Comment: Have a look at an increasing number of updates - the overhead of the loop will be minimal for ever larger numbers of updates. Of course a large program with 1,000s of copies of the same instruction will always be faster than a program that includes some logic to do a comparison and jump in addition to the instruction - but since you're doing in-place replacements, I assume you also care about the amount of memory used (and generating the program would take longer than executing the loop, so you're only moving the burden)

Comment: Let's be honest, you're guilty of premature optimization here.  The for-loop code is easier to write, easier to read, and handles arbitrary lists.  The time for the update is less than half the time of creating the list in the first place.  Code like this is almost never going to be critical path.

Comment: I expanded the length of the list to 10,000 with 5,000 indices, with a `timeit` run of 10000 I'm only observing a very minimal saving of 15.7534 (loop) vs 14.1319 (assignment), ~10% saving.  Honestly I think you spent more time posting this question than any potential savings down the line.

Comment: Before anyone dumb enough like me to try - dynamically generating the assignment codes and running them with `exec` is NOT the way to go.  Trust me on this :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing something as simple as a replacement of a list element 40 times is not really a test of how it will perform at scale. Consider this instead:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import shuffle


def f(xs, indices):
    for i in indices:
        xs[i] = int(xs[i])


def main():
    for p in range(6):
        n = 10**(p+3)
        shuffle(indices := list(range(n)))
        indices = [indices.pop() for __ in range(n // 100)]
        xs = [str(x) for x in range(n)]
        print(n, timeit(lambda: f(xs, indices), number=1) / n)


main()
```

Result:

```
1000 2.799999999997249e-09
10000 1.4999999999987245e-09
100000 2.817999999999987e-09
1000000 3.4772999999999053e-09
10000000 3.8900799999999515e-09
100000000 5.486388000000062e-09
```

(this shows the time spent on average in a single iteration, for a list of increasing length)

The size of the original list affects performance in a non-trivial way. Also, consider that the code with just replacements instructions has to come from somewhere and since you probably won't write all of it by hand for large lists, you will need to generate it - and that code is guaranteed to be more costly than the actual loop.

So either you only need this for manageably small number of updates, in which case you're right and writing out the instructions is faster - but makes your code larger (affecting load time and free memory). Or you need this for a larger number of updates and it's either not worth it since there is no efficient way to generate the code as an alternative - or you're OK with generating the code elsewhere as well as being OK with sacrificing the time and space needed to load your much larger program, with the only benefit being a marginally faster loop.

However, it seems unlikely that this is an optimisation worth looking at in the first place. The gains here are never going to be more than tiny fractions of seconds, seconds at most for extremely large lists - there must innumerable other places in your code that would allow for far greater gains.

And finally, if you insist speed matters here, you should consider doing the work in better data structures than a list of strings, or a language like Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(l[i]) if i in indexes else l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
# [4, 5, '8', '19', 2, 53, '125']
```

```
%timeit [int(l[i]) if i in indexes else l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
2.82 µs ± 566 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is a very efficient way to generate a completely new list, but OP was asking about in-place replacements (which doesn't require an entirely new list to be constructed in memory, taking up twice the space).

Comment: @Grismar IMO the bottleneck is simply that Python is slow in reading and writing the index one by one, so the only viable alternative here is creating a second list, at least to the extend of my limited knowledge.

Comment: In specific cases, replacing the list may be the better performing solution for time (although clearly never for space), but I was merely pointing out that's not what OP asked. You might want to test your hypothesis though - looking at what needs to happen, I actually doubt your solution is in fact faster.